# Autosuggest in react native

Tags: react-native, autosuggest

I have used react-native autosuggest, but it is not showing results according to what user has typed. No results are getting showed.Can you suggest me autosuggest wherein as soon as user types a text filtered results are shown and as user clicks on any element from autosuggest list then autosuggest gets closed I want it for both android and ios and also how to use it.

Answer (score 4):

[react-native-autocomplete-input](https://github.com/l-urence/react-native-autocomplete-input) is one of my favorite for the purpose